# css padding an image inside a listitem (navigation bar)

Tags: css, image, properties, background, padding

I have an image displayed for every listitem on my navigation bar, the problem is I cannot use padding left by 10px, my browser would think that the listitems need the padding left instead of my background-image.

Is there a way I can substract the background-image property from the #menu li a selector,
without affecting other background-image properties on my page?

```
#menu li a{
    display:block;
    font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;

    color:#ffffff;

    text-decoration:none;

    background-color: #376596;

    padding-top:2px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 2px; 

    background-image:url('http://images.subeta.net/smilies/6398_emoticon_smile.gif');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

you can watch my full code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xknwa/21/)

I've been looking all over the web for a solution, but my English isn't sufficient enough to search my problem because I dont know the words/terms I should ask for I'm still a rookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try background-position.

```
menu li a{
background-position:10px 0px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works, however it is messing up my menu li a: hover{ background :(

Comment: I got it fixed, just had to put background-position:0px 0px; 
in my hover selector sweet!

Comment: my reputation is to low for voting at the moment, but I will when it gets higher.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use padding on a background-image. What you can do position the image like this:

```
background-image:url('http://images.subeta.net/smilies/6398_emoticon_smile.gif') no-repeat 5px 0px;
```

It will now position 5px from left and 0 from top. Oh and delete `background-repeat:no-repeat`